# How to redirect from document root to a folder with apache2 mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have Apache2 on Ubuntu serving several hosts. Some of the hosts have Website and API parts and some folders like `uploads` which should be kept outside of the document root.
I would like to organize them in the following file structure:

```
domain
    uploads
    htdocs  //document root
        api
        site
```

The questions are:

1. how can I redirect all requests except `api` ones from document root
   to `site` folder without changing the browser uri
2. and rewrite browser uri to document root for requests made directly
   to `site` folder, i.e. instead of `/site/..` show `/..` in browser uri

I've tried the following but it causes `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site/?(.*)
RewriteRule .* /%1 [R]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a redirect loop because the rewritten URL matches the URL you want to redirect. In `.htaccess` the rewrite engine starts-over after the first rewrite, despite the presence of the `L` flag. The `L` flag simply stops the current pass, it doesn't stop all processing.

> 1. how can I redirect all requests except `api` ones from document root to `site` folder without changing the browser uri
> 2. and rewrite browser uri to document root for requests made directly to site folder, i.e. instead of `/site/..` show `/..` in
>      browser uri

You have the terminology reversed. #1 is actually a "rewrite", not a "redirect". You are internally rewriting (URL-rewrite) the request - the visible URL is not changing. And #2 is an external "redirect", not a "rewrite". As in a 3xx external redirect - the browser is being redirected.

I would also reverse the order, so you do #2 - the external redirect - first. Generally, redirects should always go before rewrites.

Try the following instead:

```
# Redirect direct requests for "/site/<anything>" to "/<anything>"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]

# Rewrite "/<anything>" to "/site/<anything>"
# except for "/api" and "/site" itself.
RewriteRule !^(api|site)/ /site%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive on the redirect that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable prevents a redirect loop. This variable is empty on the initial request and set to "200" (as in 200 OK status) after the first successful rewrite.

The 2nd rule (rewrite) uses a negated *pattern* to exclude requests to the `/api` and `/site` directories. This avoids the need for a separate condition. We then need to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable, instead of a backreference, in the *substitution* string.